# Correlation between 2 measures of the same variable with multiple datapoints per participant

Tags: correlation

My example is - monitoring of training load via 2 different methods - one uses perceived effort and the other uses external measurement of load with an algorithm. I would like to see how these correlate but each participant will perform a number of different workout sessions which will result in different scores. Therefore a number of different data pairs will be created for each participant. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could correlate the data for each participant thus ending up with $k$ estimates of the within person $r$ where there are $k$ participants. You could then average them either by taking the median or by converting using Fisher's hyperbolic arc-tangent transformation, averaging them, back transforming. That would be fine if you have equal numbers of sessions per participant, if not you would need to weight them.

Alternatively you could average each participant giving two scores per participant which you could then correlate to give you the between subjects correlation.

Each of these would be an answer to a possible scientific question.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I think option II looks the easiest - It was the method I was thinking of but worried it would breach various statistical analysis rules and assumptions. One being we are looking at the correlation of an average score and not taking into account the variance in some way.